# How to reset ARM Coretex-A76 using low level instruction?

Tags: linux, arm

I am familiar with CPU reset in X86 arch (0xCF9, keyboard controller, ACPI, etc).
But now I am working in ARM Cortex-A76 system, sometimes systemd in Linux failed to reboot/shutdown system triggered from command line.
I am wondering if there is something in Cortex-A76 similar to those mechnisms in X86 to reset/shutdown CPU ?

Comment: I believe this is generally outside the arm in the chip silicon.  so you have to look at the chip documentation for watchdog timer or how the reset controls work.

Comment: the reset and clock enable signals specifically are on the edge of the arm core so it is chip logic that manages them...(arm does not make the chip/chip logic)

Comment: an x86 pc is a well cloned system and they have matching mechanisms, arm is a free for all and each chip works differently and also each system works differently.   and arm has nothing to do with it (as intel does not necessarily drive what motherboard manufacturers or bios folks do).  for arm BASED products, you have to look at the specific chip and/or the specific board with that chip.

Comment: So, the reset in ARM is implementation defined instead of arch defined, right?

Comment: the reset into the arm logic is on the edge of the arm logic there should be a clock enable and a reset (for each core).  So the chip vendor (which is not arm) controls that reset, in their logic.  If they conform to someone elses solution or use some common logic from someone so be it, but technically it is the chip vendor.